# Label for checkbox of an html frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

How can I do like for example, if we click over the label text, I want to toggle (check/uncheck) the checkbox of **box.html** page.

I've included the box.html page, with an iframe.

**Index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="box.html" height="25px" width="100px">

        </iframe>
        <label for="box">
            checkbox
        </label>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Box.html**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="box">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498725/control-iframe-content-with-javascript-html

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: i would suggest use bootstrap template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, both the pages (Main and iframe) should be from the same domain, else it will throw cross domain error.

1st Page

```
<html><head>
<script>
    function delegate() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
        iframe.contentWindow.change();
    }
</script></head><body>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="box.html" height="25px" width="100px"></iframe>
<label for="box" onclick="delegate()">
    Click Here.
</label></body></html>
```

2nd Page

```
<html><head>
<script>
    function change() {
        document.getElementById('box').checked = !document.getElementById('box').checked;
    }
</script></head><body>
<input type="checkbox" id="box"></body></html>
```