# Event propagation in jQuery with IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, event-handling, jquery-events

I have an html file named **first.html** which has an iframe element to load another html file named **second.html**. How can we communicate between these two html files. I have tried to trigger an event from the second.html and to catch the same on first.html. But event propagation is not successful.

Here is the **first.html** file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js" /> 
<script>
   function onLoad(){
      alert("onLoad");
      var iframe = $('#iframeID').contents();
      iframe.find("#button").on("SUBMIT",function(){
          // business logic
          alert("Clicked");
      });
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <iframe id="iframeID" onload="onLoad()" height="1000" width="1000" src = './second.html'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the **second.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js" />
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            $('#button').trigger("SUBMIT");
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498725/control-iframe-content-with-javascript-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use jquery to communicate ,
Because Event bubbling stops at root of the document and that is iframe container and doesn't reach host document.
You can use the **Post message** to communicate.

Try this code it's works .

Here is the **first.html** file.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 // addEventListener support for IE8
        function bindEvent(element, eventName, eventHandler) {
            if (element.addEventListener){
                element.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
            } else if (element.attachEvent) {
                element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
            }
        }

 // Listen to message from child window
        bindEvent(window, 'message', function (e) {
           alert("Got the message from child");
        });
</script>
<body>
   <iframe   name="iframeID"   height="1000" width="1000" src = './second.html'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <head>

<button id="button" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"/>
 <script>

    function myFunction(){
    var message = 'Send the message to parent ';
       window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
     };

 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```